# sh Script with copy and removing a part from filename

Tags: copy, rename, filenames

So i use a script that copy's specific files to specific folders based on there filenames. I would like to extend the script so that after the copy progress a part from the filename is removed. Here is an example The filename looks likes this Image_000058_19_12_2019_1920x1080.jpg and i like to remove the resolution (_1920x1080) part from it. Is there a way to add it to my Script (see below) Thanks to @fedxc for the script.

````
cd "$HOME/Downloads"
# for filename in *; do
find . -type f | while IFS= read filename; do # Look for files in all ~/Download sub-dirs
  case "${filename,,*}" in  # this syntax emits the value in lowercase: ${var,,*}  (bash version 4)
     *.part) : ;; # Excludes *.part files from being moved
     move.sh) : ;;
#    *test*)            mv "$filename" "$HOME/TVshows/Glee/" ;; # Using move there is no need to {&& rm "$filename"}
     *test*)           scp "$filename" "imac@imac.local:/users/imac/Desktop/" && rm "$filename" ;;
     *american*dad*)   scp "$filename" "imac@imac.local:/users/imac/Movies/Series/American\ Dad/" && rm "$filename" ;;
     *) echo "Don't know where to put $filename" ;;
  esac
done```
````

Answer (score 0):

I use variable operation for bash. Example:

```
export filename='Image_000058_19_12_2019_1920x1080.jpg' <----Setting name of filename
echo ${filename/_1920x1080/}                            <--Operation with bash variable.
      Image_000058_19_12_2019.jpg                       <--Result of echo
```

Consult this page for more: [Bash Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_03.html)